# When can you interchange composition of a limit?

Tags: limits, continuity

I've seen some limit problems where you can do this:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp\left({g(x)}\right) = \exp \left( \lim_{x \to \infty }g(x)\right) .
$$
So, I've tried to generalize the result as:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(g(x)) = f \left( \lim_{x \to \infty }g(x) \right)
$$
and I was just wondering if the result above is actually true, and on what conditions? Perhaps someone can point me to a theorem.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=\lim_{t\to \infty}g(t)$, then the generalization is correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Continuity turns out to be the right condition. As long as $f$ is continuous and the limit of $g$ exists at the point in question, then the limit will commute with composition. That is, for a given $x$ in the domain of $g$,
$$ \lim_{x\to t} f(g(x)) = f (\lim_{x\to t} g(x))$$
When dealing with values at infinity, technically you want the functions to be continuous on the extended real line ( either two point or one point compactifications). In practice, that amounts to proving 
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$$ exists.

Comment: $g$ needs to be continuous?

Comment: Weird things could happen. If $f$ is constant and the limit of $g$ doesn't exist, then the left might exist and the right won't.

Comment: What if we guarantee that all limits exist, then. Does $g$ still need to be continuous?

Comment: If you guarantee  the limit exists, then you have verified that it's continuous. It only matters at that point, though. I should note that in my answer.

Comment: Uh, $x\mapsto\begin{cases}1,&x=0\\0,&x\ne0\end{cases}$ has the limit existing at $0$ but isn't continuous.

Comment: Right, of course. The limit only needs to exist, I think. Neither side actually cares about the value of $g$ at $x$ so you can always just patch it at that point.

Answer (score 3):

For direct substitution like that to be correct, the function you are substituting into has to be continuous at that value. For example, $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(\lim \limits_{x \to a} x) = f(a) $ only if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = \lim \limits_{x \to a} x=a$.

So your generalization would be correct if the outer function $f(x)$ is continuous at the value of the inner limit $x=\lim \limits_{t \to a} g(x)$. This could be for any value of $a$, as long as continuity is ensured.