# Proof of an energy inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to prove that:$$ E(t)\leq 0, \quad \forall t \in (0,+ \infty)\quad :(1)$$
I have proved that :$$ E(t)\leq 0 ,\quad \forall  t\in [0,T]
\quad :(2)$$
where $T$ is a finite number.

My question is can I use eq(2) to prove eq(1)?

My thought is to take limits on both sides of eq(2) so I get:
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}E(t)\leq \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}0$$
or $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}E(t)\leq 0 \quad :(3)$$
From (2) and (3)  I get$$E(t)\leq0,\quad\forall t\in[0,\infty)\quad:(4)$$Is my thought correct?
I doubt the final step of my thougt -the equation (4).Is it correct?  If it is ,how can i show it in a more accurate mathematical way?

I know that E(t) is continuous ∀t∈(0,+∞).Any help?

Comment: I believe that with $E$ being continuous - the result should be automatic, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Continuity implies being able to interchange the limit, no?

Comment: Maybe reading some of these will help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416497/when-can-you-interchange-composition-of-a-limit

Comment: Is $T$ a constant or can you choose it arbitrarily? If it is constant, (2) does not imply (1) in general. If you can choose it arbitrarily, then (1) follows immediately, since for any $t \in (0, \infty)$, you can just take $T > t$. So no limit required, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Xileflix just applied the definition of infinity since arbit T is allowed.