# Prove that the set of $n \times n$ left stochastic matrices is compact

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, compactness

I want to prove that the set of $n \times n$ left stochastic matrices is compact. This set is certainly bounded because the entries of a stochastic matrix are at most $1$. But I am having some difficulties showing that the set is closed. Suppose there is a sequence of left stochastic matrices $P_i$ that converges to $P$. Then $P$ has non-negative entries as entries of matrices in the sequence are non-negative. But how can I show that the sum of each column of $P$ is $1$? Can someone give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbf1^T(\lim_{k\to\infty}P_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}(\mathbf1^TP_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbf1^T=\mathbf1^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(P^{(k)})_k$ be a Cauchy sequence in the set of stochastic matrices. It is straightforward to show that the sequence converges to some limit $P$ (every component $(P^{(k)}_{ij})_k$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ and thus converges).

We want to show that for all $1\le j\le n$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij} = 1 $$
To see this, simply notice that [the limit of a finite sum is equal to the finite sum of the limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties), and thus for all $1\le j\le n$ we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij} =\sum_{i=1}^n\lim_{k\to\infty} (P^{(k)}_{ij} )=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n  P^{(k)}_{ij}\right) = \lim_{k\to\infty} (1) = 1\tag{*}$$
And we are done.

(*Remark :* A "faster" argument for identity $(*)$ would be to notice that $\sum_{1\le i\le n} P_{ij} = \langle P,\mathbf{1}_j\rangle$ with $\mathbf{1}_j$ the matrix with all ones on the $j$-th column and zero elsewhere. Then, because $\langle\cdot, \mathbf{1}_j\rangle$ is continuous, [we could have said that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416497/when-can-you-interchange-composition-of-a-limit) $\langle \lim_{k\to\infty}P^{(k)},\mathbf{1}_j\rangle =\lim_{k\to\infty} \langle P^{(k)},\mathbf{1}_j\rangle = 1 $.)

Comment: I see. I did not realize that it is this simple! Thank you very much!